# How to test android apps that depend on telecom provider connection?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, android-development

I am planning to write an app that needs phone number and contact list. Is there any way that I can test my app without buying a telecom provider connection for my android phone. Without a sim the phone doesn't have a phone number and I am wondering if mock phone number is only way to get pass this.

Comment: very closely related: [How can I test an application that depends on specific hardware](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/213739/31260). See also: [what should a developer know/address to build commercial Android Apps?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/51310/31260)

Comment: I was in a similar situation a couple of years ago, ended up just buying a burner for $35.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way that you can use default emulator in android and you can send a call to your emulator from DDMS. You can check some functionality using this method.

Answer (score 0):

[ADT emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) might help you a lot, with GSM carrier simulation. It also support two phone simulation for calls, etc. which is enough for many test cases.